# Does Zetsu have a word soul?

Tags: naruto

**This question contains spoilers! For early manga readers and anime viewers**

> I wonder if Zetsu would be affected by the treasured tools of the Sage of the Six Paths. One idea is that White Zetsu and Black Zetsu have different word souls. However, would each White Zetsu clone have a different word soul?

Comment: Unless it is very explicit in the manga, you might want to explain a little bit about what a word soul is.

Comment: Well, in the wiki, it refers to this link : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kotodama

Comment: You should make that clear in the question, because anyone who hasn't read that second wikipedia article won't really know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the light of Chapter 618, each Zetsu has his own soul, and thus, it is reasonable to expect that they have their own soul word.

> In Chapter 618, Orochimaru uses Edo Tensei to summon the previous four Hokage using four Zetsu's as sacrifice. Kabuto had previously explained that resurrecting the soul of a dead person with Edo Tensei requires sacrificing the soul of a living person.

Comment: Very good! I haven't thought about that!

Comment: I'm not sure you need a soul to sacrifice. I thought you only needed the body. You need to sacrifice a living body, where the summoned soul gets reincarnated. Isn't it like that?

Comment: @JNat Yeah, it is somewhat unclear, because Kabuto said that a "living person" becomes the vessel for the soul. However, the living person dies during the summoning, so I tend to think a living _soul_ is required. That is the simplest explanation. If that is not true, Naruto could use Edo Tensei using his own shadow clones as a sacrifice, which would be ridiculous.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So would they have the same soul word or different ones?

Answer (score 4):

I think neither of them even has a soul, not to mention a soul word.

> White Zetsu is a clone made by cells from Hashirama. Black Zetsu is a manifestation of Madara's willpower. Neither of them, I believe, have a soul of their own.

For that reason, I don't think that they have a soul word, because it relies on the word to be recorded from the victim's soul.

Comment: But they talk ... How should they talk if they have no soul? Also, who should control them, if they have no soul?

Comment: Clones have no soul of their own. Mind isn't equal to soul in Naruto. Tobi controls them because that's what Madara, their creator ordered.

Answer (score 2):

This is pure speculation, but I think that each clone has the same soul. White and black Zetsu have their own soul, but the clones possibly have the same soul like their originals.

> I think so, because Hashirama Senju was cloned by Madara, but it
>  doesn't have its own soul (the soul was sealed by Hokage Sarutobi).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if the treasured tools were used to seal one White Zetsu, would it seal all of them? Considering that it uses the recorded word soul, that would have been a great way to end the war!

Comment: @ChetterHummin: I thought of this, too. Maybe, they just didn't know that or I'm wrong. Or it's a plothole ... However, it's not easy to seal the soul, the treasured tools that can be used for sealing are all used.

Answer (score 1):

Shadow clones are unavailable for the sacrificial process, dude. They will simply dissapear the second they feel pain in the process. However this White Zetsus are special clones that will not dissapear no matter what damage they took, zetsus are special clones, as kisame said during his encounter with Killer Bee, Naruto, and Yamato. So basically the sacrifice needed in the ritual is a **living and useable body, the one that exist and constant**

As for Zetsus and their clones might or might not have a soul, I'm not sure about this one. They have their own mind, they talk very much, and they have a free will, yet they can be cultivated freely with Hashirama Living Clone.